# Java Regex not matching properly

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to check if a string has any equals sign on its own. My current regex does not seem to work within Java, even though [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) matches it.

My current code is:

```
String str = "test=tests";
System.out.println(str + " - " + str.matches("[^=]=[^=]"));
```

In the following test cases the first should be matched, the second shouldn't:

```
test=tests // matches t=t
test==tests // doesn't match
```

Regex Pal does it right, however, Java for some reason returns false for both test cases. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java's [`String.matches` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) matches the entire string, instead of just one part. That means, it is roughly equivalent to the regex `^[^=]=[^=]$`, so both returns false. To build a regex working equivalent to yours, you should use:

```
str.matches("(?s).*[^=]=[^=].*")
```

(The `(?s)` ensures the `.` matches everything.)

Alternatively, you could build a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and use [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for greater flexibility. This is what String.matches uses.

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^=]=[^=]");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
return m.find();
```

Comment: Aah I see! This makes sense as earlier it matches begin and end of a string even though I hadn't added ^ and $! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must add either `*` or `+` to your regexp:

```
str.matches("[^=]+=[^=]+")
```

This is needed, because `string.matches()` is anchored by default. This is equivalent to `^[^=]+=[^=]+$` and means that it must match the whole string and not only a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are just matching `single` character before and after `=`. Now, since `String#matches` tries to match the `complete` string with the given `Pattern`, so you need to ensure that you cover complete string in it. Obviously, your string does contain `many characters` before and after `=`.

So, to specify this, you need to use a `quantifier`, here: -

- `+` to match `one or more` characters
- `*` to match `zero or more` characters

So, you would need to change your regex to: -

```
System.out.println(str + " - " + str.matches("[^=]+=[^=]+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that String.matches() **does not search for a matching subsequence**, but instead tries to match the complete string against your pattern.

For your purpose, you need Matcher.find(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()